# Brand new KitchenAid Professional 6500 makes clicking/ticking noise when under load

Tags: baking, bread, equipment, dough, stand-mixer

I bought a brand new KitchenAid Professional 6500 from "kitchenaid.com" just a week ago and set it up today, I used the flap beater attachment to make cookie dough.

When mixing butter with sugar and eggs until it creams, no clicking noise can be heard.

But when adding 3 cups of flour to the mixture, clicking noise can be heard.

All of the above was done at speed: "stir".

I do not like this annoying clicking noise for a $500 mixer, completely absurd.
Had I knew about this "normal, common, not-a-big-deal" problem among the KitchenAid mixers (specially in the "professional" series) I would've originally spent $700 for a Bosch or an Ankarsrum mixer.

What exactly is causing this clicking noise when under light load such as cookie dough?
Is it the gears or the retaining pin bumping with the attachment connector? Thinking to return this...

Thanks!

Comment: Was it refurbished?  Because kitchenaid.com lists the 6500 at $600, not $500.

Comment: While under return period, I would run it hard for a long time and see if it goes away. Corn starch and water should give it a workout.

Comment: No it was not refurbished, I bought it brand new with coupon code.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that one of two things is happening:

1. The gears aren't aligned correctly, and they're far enough apart that the teeth are just barely touching, so under load, they start slip rather than mesh up correctly.
2. The sacrificial gear is failing.  Basically, there's a gear that's designed to break rather than have forces get transmitted back to the motor and cause damage that can't easily be fixed.

The first one is obviously a problem.  I don't really see this happening unless it was dropped at some point.  If you saw damage to the box, or the packaging inside the box, it's possible this is the case.

The second one is specifically designed to happen, although I wouldn't expect it to fail this quickly.  It's also designed to be repaired relatively easily.  I would recommend contacting the manufacturer, especially if you can easily reproduce the sound.

Note : I know that when repairing a friend's Kitchen Aid, I got a pair of special pliers to remove some retaining rings ... I can't remember if the sacrificial gear could be removed without it ... but there's also been a whole lot of variants of the Kitchen Aid mixers through the years that look nearly identical, but are different internally.

Comment: Alright, going to return this. I don't want my hands to get greasy and I threw out the box, not sure if I can return it and I am still in the return period. Gunna call the 1-800